# Removing the CartThrob "Ecommerce" tab

Tags: cartthrob, accessory

Does anyone know how to remove the E-commerce tab? It's not really useful for us and can't be removed as far as I can tell — which is a problem on MSM sites that cannot have access to CT.

I'm hacking it with ZooFlexible Admin but it's a pain configuring this every MSM install (there are many and it's growing).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add CartThrob Tab to CP Main Menu?
Adds a navigation tab to the CP for easy access to CartThrob settings and channels. Requires EE 2.1.5 or higher.

Are you referring to this setting? Under the Global settings for the module?

Comment: Nope. This is the other Tab called "ecommerce" it's also added. CT adds two tabs.